# How to run armhf executables on an arm64 system?

Tags: 16.04, arm64

I have Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS installed on an arm64 server:

```
# uname -a
Linux test 4.9.23-std-1 #1 SMP Mon Apr 24 13:18:14 UTC 2017 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

I ran the following command to enable `armhf` package installation:

```
# dpkg --add-architecture armhf
```

I then installed the `traceroute` package:

```
# apt-get install traceroute:armhf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
[...]
Preparing to unpack .../traceroute_1%3a2.0.21-1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking traceroute:armhf (1:2.0.21-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
```

However, I cannot launch the executable:

```
# traceroute
-bash: /usr/sbin/traceroute: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Further information:

```
# file /usr/bin/traceroute.db
/usr/bin/traceroute.db: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV),
    dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux
    2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=0ebd0553e26b163dd848c131fe8ee0a4a2409109, stripped
# ldd /usr/bin/traceroute.db
        not a dynamic executable
```

I also tried installing `binfmt-support` and confirming that the `binfmt_misc` module was loaded.

Isn't `arm64` backwards-compatible with `armhf`? How can I run `armhf` executables on an `arm64` server?

Comment: Apparently all the dependencies as well as the interpreter need to be 32-bit as well

Comment: Do you performed `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade` after `dpkg --add-architecture armhf`?

Comment: @MarcosSilveira yes, no difference.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Arm32 support is optional on arm64. In practice, there is only one arm64 CPU that omits legacy arm32 instruction set support - Cavium ThunderX.  From the kernel version string, it seems you are using Scaleway armv8 servers. If this is the case, you are out of luck - Scaleway armv8 servers are based on ThunderX. Use the Scaleway C1 instead, which is native arm32.

Comment: Good guess, I am using Scaleway. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Packet's Type 2A server is also ThunderX based and is also subject to this restriction.

Comment: Six years later, is it still the case that in practice there is only one arm64 CPU that omits it?